# SQL Найти города в которые отправлено больше всего заказов

Tags: sql

Нужно осуществить sql запрос вида: выдать в какой из множества городов в базе с заказами и городами было осуществлено максимальное количество заказов. Подскажите какой командой это можно осуществить?

Comment: Группировка, подсчёт количества, сортировка по убыванию. *какой командой это можно осуществить?* запросом SELECT.

Comment: Уж не знаю сарказм это или нет, но спасибо. А дальше как? Как посчитать количество поездок в каждый город и выдать максимальное значение?

Comment: @Yrukami мы должны с бубном плясать и шаманить структуру твоих таблиц?